# Can't create an object of a new class. Import not recognized

Tags: java, import

I'm working on a java project and I created a data transfer object so I can return multiple values from another class' method. When I try to import this class though,  it says the import cannot be resolved. Besides not using the correct path in my import, are there any other potential causes to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that first thing I said about not using the correct path on my import was correct. Well, that was easy!

Comment: You could have edited your post..

Comment: If he marks answer as accepted, it will be more useful.

Comment: Agreed with @Alfabravo.  If he placed the answer in his question, the question would never be resolved.

Comment: "User Error" has extremely little long-term value as an answer.

Comment: There are two possible actions : delete the question or accept this answer. But putting the answer in the question by editing it is forbidden on SO.

Comment: This is so irrelevant. Just leave this topic alone, you'll sleep fine. Granted.